# How to convert multiple png files to jpeg

Tags: vba, excel, png, jpeg

i've been trying to convert some files i have in a folder in .png to .jpg using vba, but i can't end up with a code to do that, i've been trying to paste the images in Excel and export them as jpg, but it doesn't seem to work, can anybody help me out with this?
I have the code where i tried to do so
I get an error on this line

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("foto").Chart.Export Filename:=x, FilterName:="JPEG"
```

Because "This member can only be accesed for a chart object"
Can anybody help me out?

```
On Error Resume Next
    DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim Pathh As String
    Dim fila As Integer
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Pathh = "C:\Users\jojeda\Desktop\Pruebas JPEG\"
    Set carpeta = fso.getfolder(Pathh)
    Set ficheros = carpeta.Files
    For Each ficheros In ficheros
    'I belive the code should be here

b = "C:\Users\jojeda\Desktop\Pruebas JPEG\" & ficheros.Name
        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(b)
        .Placement = 1
        .Name = "foto"
        .PrintObject = True
        End With
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = b
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Replace ".png", ".jpg", xlPart
        b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6)
        x = Right(b, 8)


    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("foto").Chart.Export Filename:=x, FilterName:="JPEG"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("foto").Delete
       Next ficheros

DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Avoid using `On Error Resume Next` because it just mutes error messages (see [VBA Best Practices - Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling)). Remove that line and add/[edit] to your question where you get errors (which line) and what errors you get.

Comment: Thank's peh, i just edited the question and i can see now where's the error, but i can't  figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution to my own question, i ended up loading the picture in a chart and then exporting the file as a JPEG file, in another folder, in case anyone is looking for something like this, this is the code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim Pathh As String
    Dim fila As Integer
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Pathh = "C:\Users\jojeda\Desktop\Pruebas JPEG\"
    Set carpeta = fso.getfolder(Pathh)
    Set ficheros = carpeta.Files
    For Each ficheros In ficheros
        b = "C:\Users\jojeda\Desktop\Pruebas JPEG\" & ficheros.Name
        c = "C:\Users\jojeda\Desktop\Pruebas JPEG2\" & ficheros.Name
       Set blab = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=200, Top:=80, Height:=200)
       blab.Name = "foto"
       blab.Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.UserPicture (b)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = b
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Replace ".png", ".jpeg", xlPart
        b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("foto").Chart.Export Filename:=c, FilterName:="JPEG"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("foto").Delete
       Next ficheros

DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer as solution. So anyone can see that this question is solved.

Comment: Thaks Peh, I tried that when I solved the question, but I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer :(